# Regularity, Dirichlet form

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, stochastic-calculus

I have a question about Dirichlet form.

Let $\Omega$ be an Euclidean domain of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and 
$X=\bar{\Omega}$. The measure $m$ on the Borel 
$\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is given by $m(A)=\lambda(A \cap \Omega)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ with $\lambda $ the Lebesgue measure. It follows that $L^{2}(\Omega)=L^{2}(X,\mathcal{B}(X),m)$. We define a Dirichlet form on $L^{2}(\Omega)$ by 
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{E}(f,g)=\int_{\Omega}\left(\nabla f,\nabla g \right)\,dx,\quad f,g \in \widetilde{H}^{1}(\Omega),
\end{equation*}
where $\widetilde{H}^{1}(\Omega)=\text{closure of }H^{1}(\Omega)\cap C_{c}(\bar{\Omega}) \text{ in } H^{1}(\Omega)$. $C_{c}(\bar{\Omega})$ denotes all continuous reak valued function on $\bar{\Omega}$ with support and $H^{1}(\Omega) \cap C_{c}(\bar{\Omega})=\left\{ f \left| \right._{\Omega} \in H^{1}(\Omega) : f \in C_{c}(\bar{\Omega}) \right\}$.

**Question**

I want to check the following assertion:

\begin{align*}
&(1) \quad \widetilde{H}^{1}(\Omega) \cap C_{c}(\bar{\Omega}) \text{ is dense in } C_{c}(\bar{\Omega}) \text{ w.r.t. sup norm}.
\end{align*}

**My attempt**

(1): It is enough to show that for all $ f \in C_{c}(\bar{\Omega})$, $\epsilon>0$, there exists $g \in H_{1}(\Omega) \cap C_{c}(\bar{\Omega})$ such that $\|f-g\|<\epsilon$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is sup norm.

Take $f \in C_{c}(\bar{\Omega})$. By Tietze extension theorem, we can find $F \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $F=f$ on $\bar{\Omega}$. Define $F_{\delta}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}j_{\delta}(x-y)F(y)\,dy$, where $j_{\delta}$ is standard mollifier. Then $F_{\delta } \to f$ uniformly on $\text{supp} [f]$ and $F_{\delta} \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. But I don't know how to prove $F_{\delta} \left|_{\Omega} \right. \in H_{1}(\Omega) \cap C_{c}(\bar{\Omega})$.

Please tell me how to prove (2). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $\Omega$ open? What is your definition of $C_c(\bar\Omega)$? If $\Omega$ is bounded, the usual definition would give $C_c(\bar\Omega) = C(\bar\Omega)$, since $\bar\Omega$ is already compact. Is this intended?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, $\Omega$ is an open subset on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $C_{c}(\bar{\Omega})$ denotes the space of all continuous real valued functions on $\bar{\Omega}$ with compact support.

Comment: Hence, $C_c(\bar\Omega) = C(\bar\Omega)$?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is bounded, $C_{c}(\bar{\Omega})=C(\bar{\Omega})$. But $\Omega$ is an arbitary open subet of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: What does the Dirichlet form have to do with your quesiton?

Comment: @JonWarneke: Assertion (1) is part of the statement that the Dirichlet form is regular.  But as you say, you don't really need to know about Dirichlet forms to make sense of the question; it just provides context.

Answer (score 0):

To check $F_\delta = j_\delta * F$ restricted to $\Omega$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$, i.e., $D F_\delta |_\Omega \in L^2(\Omega)$, we have from properties of convolution that
\begin{align*}
D F_\delta = D(j_\delta * F) = (D j_\delta) * F.
\end{align*}
Now, $(D j_\delta) * F$ has compact support $K$ (contained in the compact support of $F$) and is smooth (inheriting smoothness of $D j_\delta$ -- this is another property of convolution), and hence belongs to $C_c^\infty(K)$. It follows that it has finite $L^2$ norm since $C_c^\infty(K) \subset C_c(K) \subset L^2(K)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't know support of $(Dj_{\delta}) \ast F$ is contained in the compact support of $F$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake. A remedy that might work: additionally require the $j_\delta$ to have compact support, which is possible. The compact support (and smoothness) arguments I made then go through, but the support may not be in $K$. It seems that you only care about restriction to $\Omega$, though, so this shouldn't be an issue.